# @font-face not loading in IE with https

Tags: internet-explorer, https, font-face

i noticed that my font-face will not load when in https mode - only on IE (8 or 9).

any ideas why?

here is a sample page: https://www.kby.org/test/font.asp

you should be seeing 3 small icons. if you see the letters 2PK then font-face is not working...

thanks!

Comment: Works for me in IE 9 (Windows 7 32 bit) although it shows `2PK` for half a second before changing into icons.

Comment: mmm... thanks for checking. weird. i am on Windows 7, 64 bit, IE9 - and it just remains 2Pk...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue https with IE9 not showing on win7 64bit, I changed how the browser got information. The way [fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/blog/2010/11/troubleshooting-font-face-problems) advised (really useful site for automatically generating you your font-face.css file in the latest syntax), was to put inbetween the head tags of the HTML: the link to the stylesheet and the css on the actual HTML page e.g.

```
    <link href="/includes/font-face.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style>
     body{font-family:modern_pictogramsnormal}
    </style>
```

This didn't work for me and so I tried other ways of getting the information to the browser.
Try putting an import line at the top of one of your other CSS files that will be used on this page e.g.:

```
    @import "/includes/font-face.css";
```

at the top of the your heb.css file, and take the stylesheet link to '/includes/font-face.css' out of the HTML. That is put an import line on another css file that is used in the page, I put it in my main CSS file.

This method worked for me, but I still get FOUT (Flash Of Unstyled Text) in IE9, you search for FOUT there are discussions as to whether this is good or bad and JavaScript/JQuery plugins that can delay the browser from showing text until the font has loaded properly.

If that doesn't work you could have a look at this answer I found that didn't work for me, it basically involves doubling the size of your font-face.css, instead of relative links use the whole

```
http://mydomain.com/fontfile.xxx
```

to describe myfont0, and another one using

```
https://mydomain.com/fontfile.xxx
```

to describe myfont1 then in the CSS use body{myfont0, myfont1}, sorry I can't find the link - I've been clearing my cache a lot recently, see below if you don't understand:

```
    @font-face {
font-family: 'droid_sansregular';
src: url('http://mydomain.com/fonts/droidsans-webfont-webfont.eot');
src: url('http://mydomain.com/fonts/droidsans-webfont-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('http://mydomain.com/fonts/droidsans-webfont-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('http://mydomain.com/fonts/droidsans-webfont-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('http://mydomain.com/fonts/droidsans-webfont-webfont.svg#droid_sansregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;}

     @font-face {
font-family: 'droid_sansregular0';
src: url('https://mydomain.com/fonts/droidsans-webfont-webfont.eot');
. . .}

body{font-family: droid_sansregular, droid_sansregular0}
```